# modifying local environment in python

Tags: python, django

I need to inject same variables into settings.py for multiple django apps.hence i wrote a module which takes in output of local() and modifies. This works but is it the right way to do things?

```
def enable_theme(theme_name, container):
"""
Enable the settings for a custom theme, whose files should be stored
in ENV_ROOT/themes/THEME_NAME (e.g., edx_all/themes/stanford).

The THEME_NAME setting should be configured separately since it can't
be set here (this function closes too early). An idiom for doing this
is:

   THEME_NAME = "stanford"
   enable_theme(THEME_NAME)
"""
    container["THEME_NAME"] = theme_name
    container['MITX_FEATURES']['USE_CUSTOM_THEME'] = True
    # Calculate the location of the theme's files
    theme_root = container['THEME_ROOT'] / "themes" / theme_name
    # Include the theme's templates in the template search paths
    container['TEMPLATE_DIRS'].append(theme_root / 'templates')
    container['THEME_SASS_DIRECTORY'] = theme_root / 'static/saas'
    container['MAKO_TEMPLATES']['main'].append(theme_root / 'templates')
    # Namespace the theme's static files to 'themes/<theme_name>' to
    # avoid collisions with default edX static files
    container['STATICFILES_DIRS'].append((u'themes/%s' % theme_name,
                                   theme_root / 'static'))
    container['FAVICON_PATH'] = 'themes/%s/images/favicon.ico' % theme_name

#Test case
from theming_utils.template_customizer import enable_theme
THEME_NAME = "sokratik"
PIPELINE = False
MITX_FEATURES['USE_DJANGO_PIPELINE'] = False
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
enable_theme(THEME_NAME, locals())
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't use `local()`. Also, you need to format your code so that it shows up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You're not trying to modify a local environment, you're trying to modify the module's dictionary, which you can access by calling [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals).

Note: the dictionary returned by [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) isn't meant to be modified.

Comment: that explains a bit of stuff, in case I am actually using globals, is it fine to modify globals in this way??

Comment: It's okay to modify a module's dictionary, I don't know whether or not it's the right way to handle themes in Django.